# Как исправить "тормознутость" Linux Debian на Virtual Box?

Tags: linux, debian, virtualbox

Поставил на Virtual Box Linux debian, подключил образ диска дополнений гостевой ОС, выделил видеопамять, оперативки, процессоры. В общем, все должно быть хорошо, однако в самой ОС, а вернее в ее интерфейсе, заметны микролаги, будто бы fps 20-30.

Быть может, это нормально? Или все-таки есть пути решения, чтобы ОС летала как основная?

P.S. При установке дополнений гостевой ОС, в конце, появляется такая строка:
`VirtualBox Guest Additions: modprobe vboxsf failed` Что это значит? Может, это как-то влияет на мою ситуацию?
 [image: f]

Comment: Какой DE? какой-нить третьегном AFAIK настолько прибит гвоздями к аппаратному ускорению, что ни как... ЗЫ: если дебиан не самый древний, то я бы рекомендовал устанавливать дополнения из реп, а не ручками...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, да, видимо проблема в DE, поставил cinnamon - вроде, нормально, не идеально, конечно, но все же